# Determine whether the domino server is running or not ( session.getDatabase(..) takes too long when the corresponding server is down )

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have approximately 4-5 users on different servers and need to find free time based on the calendar entries. Till last night the functionality was working great, however, today we just figured out a small **issue/bug**. One of the server machine was offline today and SSJS took around a minute (60 seconds) to figure that out.

Is there any such option to verify whether the server is running? I am asking this since *session.getDatabase* takes a long time to provide any results in such case.

Just for reference, below is my code to verify users mail database accessibility. It works perfectly fine when all servers are up, however, the waiting time is too long when any server is down.

```
// Set up the names

var names = new java.util.Vector();
var inaccessible_calendars = new java.util.Vector();
var infoDoc:NotesDocument= database.getDocumentByUNID(context.getUrlParameter('refId'));
var members:java.util.Vector = infoDoc.getItemValue("members");
names = infoDoc.getItemValue("members");
//var members:java.util.Vector = infoDoc.getItemValue("members");
var membersIterator = members.iterator();
var maildb ="";

while(membersIterator.hasNext()){
var val = membersIterator.next();
var nab:NotesDatabase=session.getDatabase(database.getServer(),"names.nsf")
var nview:NotesView=nab.getView("($NamesFieldLookup)")
var doc:NotesDocument=nview.getDocumentByKey(val,true)
if(doc){
        var email = doc.getItemValueString("MailFile")
        var emailServer = doc.getItemValueString("MailServer")
        doc.recycle()
        nview.recycle()
        nab.recycle()
        maildb=@LowerCase(emailServer)+'!!'+@LowerCase(email)+ '.nsf'
        var emailServerCN = @Name("[CN]",@LowerCase(emailServer));
        var emailDBName =   @LowerCase(email)+ '.nsf';
        emailDBName = emailDBName.replace("\\","\/");
        try{
            if(session.getDatabase(emailServerCN.toString(),emailDBName.toString())==null){
            names.remove(val);
            inaccessible_calendars.add(val);
            }else{
            var emailDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(emailServerCN.toString(),emailDBName.toString());
            if(!(emailDB.getCurrentAccessLevel()>0)){
                names.remove(val);
                inaccessible_calendars.add(val);
                }
            }
            }catch(err){
                names.remove(val);
                inaccessible_calendars.add(val);
           }
          } else {
         nview.recycle()
         nab.recycle()
         maildb= ""  
        }
}
if(!inaccessible_calendars.isEmpty())
return "Following calendars are not accessible"+inaccessible_calendars.toString()+"*";
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can shorten timeouts in port settings. How short response time do you accept? Server/network may be slow, not down.

Comment: I am sorry, I just did not notice the comment. We expect a response time of say maximum 5 -10 seconds as of now it is taking somewhere around a minute before failing. Can you just brief your solution a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Are these database in a cluster? Can they be?  If so then when you open it there an "OpenWithFailOver" method I forget the exact syntax.  But if the database in unavailable it should open another in the cluster.

Comment: Well, I don't think so..It is just that we have our mail files distributed over 3 PERSONAL development servers and trying to access them..